# How to pass regex in presidio library

Tags: python, regex, parameters

I want to recognize my custom pattern using Microsoft's Presidio library in python.
while passing the regex I am getting this error.
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'

````
from presidio_analyzer import PatternRecognizer
regex = ("^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\" +
             "s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$")
#p = re.compile(regex)
aadhar_number_recognizer = PatternRecognizer(supported_entity="AADHAR_NUMBER",
                                      patterns=[regex])```
````

Answer (score 0):

PatternRecognizer receives list of 'Pattern' objects as the 'patterns' argument. You are passing plain regex string.

Should be:

```
from presidio_analyzer import PatternRecognizer, Pattern

aadhar_number_recognizer = PatternRecognizer(supported_entity = "AADHAR_NUMBER",
                                                     deny_list=[],
                                                     patterns=[Pattern(name="AADHAR Number", score=0.8, 
                                                                       regex="(^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$)")],
                                                     context=[])
```

For more references you can take a look at how Presidio implements PatternRecognizer in its built-in recognizers.

Comment: this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this. Although I'm using a different Regex, you can use the code below as a template.

In the example I'm using the base sentence:
"Hi, Java is awesome"

and by using Presidio custom Regex it will be "anonymized" into:
"Hi, Python is awesome"

The code below is just an example, if you just want to replace "Java" with "Python" there are easier ways. This was just the first thing that came to mind. When anonymizing it makes more sense to replace "Java" or "Python" with something like <PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE>.

```
from presidio_analyzer import PatternRecognizer, Pattern
from presidio_anonymizer import AnonymizerEngine
from presidio_anonymizer.entities import OperatorConfig


base_sentence = "Hi, Java is awesome!"

# Define the regex pattern in a Presidio `Pattern` object:
java_pattern = Pattern(name="java_pattern",regex="Java", score = 0.5)
# Define the recognizer with one or more patterns
java_pattern = PatternRecognizer(supported_entity="JAVA", patterns = [java_pattern])    


java_pattern_result = java_pattern.analyze(text=base_sentence, entities=["JAVA"])
print("Sentence:", base_sentence)
print("Found:", java_pattern_result)
print()

# Now anonymize
# Initialize the engine:
engine = AnonymizerEngine()
anonymize_result = engine.anonymize(
    text=base_sentence,
    analyzer_results=java_pattern_result,
    operators={"JAVA":OperatorConfig("replace",
                                {"new_value": "Python"})})

print("Anonymized result:")
print(anonymize_result)
```

This will print:

```
Sentence: Hi, Java is awesome!
Found: [type: JAVA, start: 4, end: 8, score: 0.5]

Anonymized result:
text: Hi, Python is awesome!
items:
[
    {'start': 4, 'end': 10, 'entity_type': 'JAVA', 'text': 'Python', 'operator': 'replace'}
]
```